Live streaming on YouTube using React Native App
How can I stream on YouTube using my react-native app?. I can get the streamUrl & streamKey but unable to stream the video to YouTube. I can see my broadcast as "UPCOMING" on youtube's live section.
Help needed.
Thanks in advance
